# AccessViolationException when calling WorkflowInvoker.Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to run a parallel foreach loop with 32 threads.

This foreach loop is calling a:

```
WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(new MyWorkflow(), myInputDictionary)
```

The parallel foreach loop consists of a list of around 65000 items.

At some point, at around 6000 - 6700 items the invocation of WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(new MyWorkflow(), myInputDictionary) throws
an AccessViolationException with the message: 
    "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

I have tried different things, like creating an instance of the WorkflowInvoker and passing an instance of MyWorkflow directly to the newly created WorkflowInvoker and then calling the Invoke method on the class.
Also just calling the WorkflowInvoker.Invoke as a static method, but it doesn't make a difference. 
The application crashes at the same point every time. Because of the threads it's hard to debug and pinpoint exactly what is causing the trouble.

Of course the problems doesn't occur if I'm doing the calls in a normal foreach loop.

At first we thought the virtual machine was running low on memory, because the application started eating all available memory until it reached a limit of 85% of the total memory (4GB) and then it seemed to crash. So we changed the memory size to 1GB, to see if we could induce the exception earlier in the loop, but instead Windows started garbagecollecting, so in the end the exception still occured at the same point around 6000 - 6700 items.

Any suggestions as to what should be my next move, is much appreciated ;-)

-- EDIT - Added the full stacktrace --

```
at System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.nCreateISymWriterForDynamicModule(Module module, String filename)
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModuleInternalNoLock(String name, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModuleInternal(String name, Boolean emitSymbolInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(String name, Boolean emitSymbolInfo)
at System.Activities.Debugger.StateManager.InitDynamicModule(String asmName)
at System.Activities.Debugger.StateManager..ctor(Properties properties, Boolean debugStartedAtRoot)
at System.Activities.Debugger.DebugManager..ctor(Activity root, String moduleNamePrefix, String typeNamePrefix, String auxiliaryThreadName, Boolean breakOnStartup, WorkflowInstance host, Boolean debugStartedAtRoot)
at System.Activities.Debugger.DebugController.EnsureActivityInstrumented(ActivityInstance instance, Boolean primeCurrentInstance)
at System.Activities.Debugger.DebugController.ActivityStarted(ActivityInstance activityInstance)
at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteRootWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.OnExecuteWorkItem(WorkItem workItem)
at System.Activities.Runtime.Scheduler.Callbacks.ExecuteWorkItem(WorkItem workItem)
at System.Activities.Runtime.Scheduler.OnScheduledWork(Object state)
at System.Runtime.Fx.SendOrPostThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(Object state)
at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.PumpBasedSynchronizationContext.WorkItem.Invoke()
at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.PumpBasedSynchronizationContext.DoPump()
at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Invoke(Activity activity, IDictionary`2 inputs, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(Activity workflow, IDictionary`2 inputs, TimeSpan timeout, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions)
at System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(IDictionary`2 inputs)
```

-- Extra edit - added the method in question - Obfuscated it a bit to remove businesslogic names --

```
public MyOutputData InvokeMyWorkflow(MyInputData input) 
{
      IDictionary<string, object> wfInput = new Dictionary<string, object>
       {
        { "ArgData", input }
       };
  MyWorkflow myWorkflow = new MyWorkflow();
  try
  {
       WorkflowInvoker invoker = new WorkflowInvoker(myWorkflow);
       IDictionary<string, object> output = invoker.Invoke(wfInput);
       return output["ArgData"] == null ? null : (MyOutputData)output["ArgData"];
  }
  catch (Exception ace)
  {
           Log.Error(ace.StackTrace);
       return null;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Using a non thread-safe object, like a Dictionary, and not properly protecting it with the **lock** keyword is a good way to crash code.

Comment: An AccessViolationException should not be possible to induce in safe managed code. Can you post all of the exception so that we can at least guess the root cause?

Comment: @HansPassant - the dictionary is added inside an instance method and hence should only exist in one context, so I don't see why I should put a lock on it.

Comment: @usr - I've added the full stacktrace. I can't catch the Exception at all.

Comment: I think your best bet is to condense this into a small repro app in order to find a workaround. Also send it to Microsoft.

Comment: I can help wondering why you would want to launch 65000 workflows at the same time?

Apart from that you probably have hit some kind of bug which only surfaces under memory pressure. Are you running under 32/64 bit OS? And 32/64bit/AnyCpu configuration?

Comment: @TorbenRahbekKoch - We're not interested in running 65000 workflows at the same time - just 32 ;-)
The scenario today is that I need to process every item in the list (+65000 items). At the moment we're doing the processing in 1 thread, which means it takes forever. If we could move this process from a single threaded process to a multithreaded process, things would speed up.
We've tested the application on a Windows 7 x64 with 4GB or 1GB of RAM and the application crashes at the same point. Only difference is that the GC begins to garbagecollect when the machine only has 1GB of RAM.

Comment: @TorbenRahbekKoch - besides, we've tried with 2, 16, 32 and 64 threads. The same exception at around 6000 - 6700 items. Every time ;(
Also tried with the same item at every spot in the list, just to be sure, that it wasn't corrupt data, that was causing the exception.
Bare in mind, that this process works perfectly in 1 thread.

Comment: Darwind - that is weird, I agree! As @usr suggested: try making a small repro and open a ticket with MS. And please let us know when you/MS figure it out!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'll try to make a small repro and open a ticket with MS - already created a thread on MSDN, but with no answers at all ;(
I'll check back here, when/if I get an answer from MS.

Comment: Small update: We've managed to successfully process all the lines in the list with a Parallel.ForEach with 32 threads. ;-) What we did was run the application in Release mode instead of Debug mode... this seems to be a bug in Visual Studio 2010 - haven't tried in any other versions though.